# how do i load content into a page from another page with the associated jquery function that makes it work (slider)

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

yes that's right , I have a slider on html page B and have a menu option that when selected on html page A will load the content of a div in this case a slider into the space defined as tile-are-main... question is how do I also load the associated jquery that makes the slider work ? ?

The line of code to load the content is as follows....
main html page menu option

```
 $(".tile-area-main").load("referrals.html .slider");
```

html page B where slider and content resides....

```
<div class="slider"><!-- The slider -->
    <div><!-- A mandatory div used by the slider -->
        <!-- Each div below is considered a slide -->
        <div><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/400/300"/></div>
        <div><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/400/200"/></div>
        <div><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/200/300"/></div>
        <div><img src="http://placekitten.com/g/300/200"/></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

lets just say for arguments sake that there is a script and a js file that are both assocaited with the slider working properly.....

EDIT ....
actually this is the code that makes the slider work .....

```
<script src="js/slider/jquery.diyslider.js"></script>
      <script>$(".slider").diyslider(); // this is all you need!</script>
<script>// initialize the slider
$(".slider").diyslider({
    width: "400px",
    height: "400px",
    animationEasing: "linear",
    animationDuration: 2000,
    animationAxis: "y"
});

// set up a timer to change slides automatically
$(".slider").diyslider("move", "forth");
setInterval(function(){
    $(".slider").diyslider("move", "forth");
}, 2000);</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make that code from page B available on page A. Using `load` will not execute the js. Ideally, you could create a function and then, just call the function, instead of writing all that code on 2 separate pages.

From jQuery: jQuery uses the browser's .innerHTML property to parse the retrieved document and insert it into the current document. During this process, browsers often filter elements from the document such as , , or  elements. As a result, the elements retrieved by .load() may not be exactly the same as if the document were retrieved directly by the browser.

Script Execution

When calling .load() using a URL without a suffixed selector expression, the content is passed to .html() prior to scripts being removed. This executes the script blocks before they are discarded. If .load() is called with a selector expression appended to the URL, however, the scripts are stripped out prior to the DOM being updated, and thus are not executed.

Read More here: http://api.jquery.com/load/

```js
/**
 * Add to both page A and page B.
 * diysInit.js or in your concatenated and minified file
 * @example diysInit();
 */


function diysInit() {
  $(".slider").diyslider({
    width: "400px",
    height: "400px",
    animationEasing: "linear",
    animationDuration: 2000,
    animationAxis: "y"
  });

  // set up a timer to change slides automatically
  $(".slider").diyslider("move", "forth");
  setInterval(function() {
    $(".slider").diyslider("move", "forth");
  }, 2000);
}
```

Comment: yes , even if i do put the same code on both pages it still doesn't work .. i don't even know how i would go about this kind of function ?

Comment: If it works on page B, there is no reason it won't work when all the correct pieces are added to page A.  See my updated answer.

Comment: there must be another script embedded in a multipushmenu plugin i am using that somehow clears the script that is coded into the other page itself... i wonder if there is a way to load all scripts of the entire site into cache and keep them there ??

Comment: looking at the concepts out there it seems perhaps this might work , what do you think ?   jQuery.ajax({
      url: "jquery.slider.js",
      dataType: "script",
      cache: true
})

Answer (score 0):

try

```
 $(".tile-area-main").load("referrals.html .slider" , function(){
       $(".slider").diyslider();
});
```